# Is there a better TGridPanel somewhere?

Tags: delphi, gridpanel

has any 3rd party developer created a component similiar to Delphi's GridPanel? But better? Easier?

Comment: This question would be improved by some specifics of what problems you have with TGridPanel.

Comment: Specifics? the gridpanel has alot of problems but that wasnt my question. I just wanted to know if someone made a better component that is similiar. Just about every component Delphi has, has been improved by private parties... I am just hoping someone improved the gridpanel. Do not know why you down voted my question. It is a specific question.... your question is a different topic.

Comment: What does better mean?  Better is a subjective, unanswerable criteria. Please state what you want it to do that Delphi's grid panel doesn't do?  What does easy mean? How exactly is it hard to use GridPanel and what would like us to assume you were doing with it?

Comment: You would get answers if you provided some details

Comment: unanswerable?? Similiar component to gridpanel means basically the same. If I wanted a similiar tpanel there are hundreds if not thousands... and then I would have to be more specific...but is there even a single component by anyone that has the same attributes or mannerisms as the gridpanel supplied by EMB? TGridPanel Definition-> "The grid panel is used to arrange controls in a grid". Are there any other components by 3rd party developers that do what the tgridpanel does?

Comment: I agree with Logman. TGridPanel seems to be a still "under construction" control. The documentations certainly is. Many things like UpdateControlsRow are missing.           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589677/removing-controls-from-a-tgridpanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the  DevExpress Layout Control that has similar, but much more advanced, functionality. http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExLayoutControl/ It's not free but well worth the money.